Is there a good way to publicize JSON schema defined in Go structs through an API?
Background
I am writing a REST API, in Go, that focuses on queueing background jobs in a generic format. This is done by posting "Job Requests" that look like the following:
{
  "job_request": {
    "job_type": "user_refresh",
    "job_params": {
      "user_id": "1234ABCD"
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "created_at": "2024-04-16T20:18:45.98268Z",
    "updated_at": "2024-04-16T20:43:43.660926Z"
  }
}

There are several different jobs in our platform that utilize this generic API for asynchronous scheduling, and these are enumerated with the job_type parameter. The schema for job_params is completely dependent on the value of job_type.
In the business logic, we hide job servicing behind interfaces, and call the right implementation by switching over the job type. The exact schema for job_params lives inside of each implementation file, and this is where we do that part of the request body validation. For example: I have a user_refresh_job_servicer.go with the following struct:
type UserRefreshJobParams struct {
    userID            string     `json:"user_id"`
    optionalUserName  *string    `json:"user_name,omitempty"` // unused in the above example
} 

This is working well in that the HTTP handler and business logic for servicing these requests are dead simple. Adding a new job just means defining a schema for job_params, adding a new job_type enumeration value, and then adding a business logic implementation.
The Issue
As we have been implementing additional job types, with their own set of unique parameters, the API documentation has gotten unwieldy and large. Users and management have been requested a new set of endpoints that enumerate all the different job_type's, including the different fields in their respective job_params.
Can a representation of the JSON schemas be generated directly from the Go types? I'm trying to avoid a situation where developers have to maintain, in code, separate Go structs that represent schema for the parameter structures.
Currently, I document job_params JSON schema for each new supported type in Swagger documentation.
The new feature request is an endpoint like this:
GET /jobs/job_parameter_schemas?job_type=user_refresh
Response:
{
  "job_param_schema": {
    "job_type": "user_refresh",
    "job_params": [
      {
          "name": "user_id",
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
      }
    ],
  }
}

